# Do Chrome and Firefox have command line options similar to IE's -noframemerging?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari, opera

I am writing a program that acts like a private web server that can be launched when a resource CD is auto-run.  Once this server is started, it binds itself to an ephemeral TCP port and will then launch a browser to display the resource CD content.  My hope was for this web server to automatically shut down once the process that it launched for the web browser was dismissed by the user.  What I found, however, is that if the browser process was already running (I tried this on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and IE), the process that the web server launched served merely to start a new tab in the browser and then shut down.  I managed to find a work-around for IE by invoking the executable with the -noframemerging command line option but I have not been as successful for other browsers.

Does anyone know if Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera have command line options that will disable this frame-merging behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome, use the --new-window command line switch.  For Firefox, it's -new-window. Not sure about the other two.

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

Comment: I just tried this out.  With Chrome, at least, the browser does show a new window but, if the browser is already running, the process that my application starts ends.  I'm afraid that this does accomplish what I need.  Thanks anyway.